# Do I need to use OpenSDA to program and debug MKL46Z256VLL4?

Tags: microcontroller, firmware

I am a novice to uC programming, though I have made simple circuits with the AVR ATMEGA series. For the AVRs, I used an ISP programming header along with the ATMEL-ICE. From what I am reading for the MKL46Z256VLL4 uC, it uses something called OpenSDA. I can see that the development board uses a PK20DX128VFM5 uC as the interface between the host computer and the target uC, the MKL46Z256VLL4.

Though if I am going to be implementing this into a product and need board space, do I need to use OpenSDA along with its circuitry? Is there something like the ATMEL-ICE for the MKL46Z256VLL4 uC that I can simply buy for ISP programming and debugging? My research shows that this would be the equivalent device but I am not quite sure:
https://www.digikey.com/products/en?mpart=U-MULTILINK&v=568

I am also not sue if it can be used with mcuxpresso.

PS: I am getting trained in embedded C in a few weeks and this is the uC we will be learning on along with using mcuxpresso. I am trying to get everything figured out for a development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question but I wanted to close this with an answer. I wound up not using this IC but no, you do not need to use OpenSDA. The multilink tool would have been acceptable as well.

Comment: What's really needed is a flexible SWD adapter with appropriate PC software.  Eg a (potentially open source) CMSIS-DAP as found on the corresponding EVB, an FT2232 software solution...  What's less clear is if a high level adapter targeted at a different ARM Cortex would work, eg, an ST/LINK can be used for some non-ST parts but has quirks which make it incompatible with other targets.